# Pandoc Lua Filters: pairs does not show all keys in table

Tags: pandoc, lua-table

Since Pandoc version 2.0, there has been the ability to write [Lua Filters](http://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html). However, in Pandoc 2.0, I find that using Lua's `pairs` on an element table does not show all keys in the table.

Here is a minimal example to illustrate the point. In `filter.lua` I have:

```
function Para(elem)
  io.stderr:write("A: " .. type(elem) .. "\n")
  for k, v in pairs(elem) do
    io.stderr:write("B: " .. k .. "\n")
  end
  io.stderr:write("C: " .. elem["t"] .. "\n")
  io.stderr:write("D: " .. tostring(elem["c"]) .. "\n")
  -- Return elem unchanged
  return nil
end
```

Now from the command-line, I run:

```
echo "Hello." | pandoc -f markdown -t native --lua-filter filter.lua
```

This produces the output:

```
A: table
B: c
C: Para
D: table: 0x53adb40
[Para [Str "Hello."]]
```

I can change the `-t native` to `-t json` so that the last line becomes:

```
{"blocks":[{"t":"Para","c":[{"t":"Str","c":"Hello."}]}],"pandoc-api-version":[1,17,2],"meta":{}}
```

So from the output at (B), it looks like `c` is the only key in `elem`, but from (C) it is clear that `t` is also a key as I can access it to obtain `Para`. What is happening here and why is the `t` key hidden from the loop done with `pairs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `t` value is hidden in the element's metatable: instead of assigning a `t` value to each element, pandoc sets a metatable for each element. The reason for this is to find a balance between usability and performance.

It is quite a bit faster to get numeric table indices back into Haskell than it is to access string-indexed values.  However, users should be able to use the element in a straight-forward object oriented way, accessing element components via readable string attributes.  This is why we assign metatables to each element.  The metatable contains info on the element type (e.g., Plain vs. Para etc.) and defines accessors (e.g., `content` is aliases to index `0` in Plain and Para elements).

So one can get the type of an element `elem` by calling `elem.t`, but the element itself doesn't have that key, the metatable does. That's why `t` does not show up when iterating over the element using `pairs`. One can use the `getmetatable` function to receive the metatable.

You might appreciate the following method to get the name of accessors (undocumented and subject to change).

```
for k, _ in pairs(getmetatable(elem).getters) do
    print k
end
```

Alternatively, the section on "Module pandoc" in the lua filters documentation lists the accessors for each element type.